# How to place button exactly in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I found a piece of code that should place a button inside the boundaries of a cell:

```
    'put a button in a cell for easy access to the value
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    Set targetCell = sheet.Range(lastRow(columns("Button1").Index).Address)
    Set btn = sheet.Buttons.Add(targetCell.Left, targetCell.Top, targetCell.Width, targetCell.Height)
```

Problem is that the button is placed halfway across the previous row somehow. Is there some way of calibrating the placement, or is there something else wrong with this?

Comment: Do you have the window zoom set to something other than 100%?

Comment: That was in fact the case! Is there some way to force 100% before adding the button?

Comment: Sure - just use: `activewindow.zoom = 100`

Answer (score 0):

"targetCell.Left, targetCell.Top, targetCell.Width, targetCell.Height" Itself is a perfect caliberation. I just need the image of the btn that is placed wrongly.

Comment: I uploaded an image to show what's currently wrong.

Comment: I don't find any link for the image.